# Are we treating objects as objects?

Tags: oop, methods

Method naming is done seeing objects as some data on which *we* operate, thus `getValue` means *I'm getting the value*. Though, in the method's description, we always read about the object doing something, and not us.

When it's about object's own data, shouldn't we choose method names from the object's point of view?

Thus, since the object *gives* its value, then method's name would be `giveValue`.

While the "setter" would be named `getValue`, since the object is getting the value.

My (annoying) question is mainly because of the *get* term, used for both retrieving data from the object or asking the object retrieve data from somewhere.

getValue → "return the value"
getData → "call another object and get some data"

Comment: I think this is too philosophical even for programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: But it' s still us who is interacting with the code and to name a setter "get" would be confusing for US. And we have to feel comfortable with the code.

Comment: while your at it, overthrow the imperial system and the base10 number system

Comment: This is why Python properties and Ruby accessors are so great: no more `get`, no more `set`, just attribute syntax.

Answer (score 4):

By your own logic, I would say it is called `Get` because the object gets a value from its internal data, and returns it to the caller. The meaningful action here is getting the data, which varies depending on the property, and not returning it to the user, which is constant.

Other than that, the point of naming methods is to give them names that would make it very clear what they do. Naming your setter `GetValue` would be nothing short of sadistic to your user.

Comment: When an object has a method that retrieves data from somewhere, we name that method `getData`, since we tell the object to _get_ some data. getData → the objects gets. So the meaning is "let's ask the object doing this".

Comment: @donkeydown: Exactly.

Answer (score 2):

> When it's about object's own data, shouldn't we choose method names from the object's point of view?

No because in essence the object is simply a container which we use to store/carry information. Programming is about writing code which is easy to use & understand from the *developers* point of view, not an objects.

Answer (score 1):

Think of it as a conversation with the object:

Object please get me your value; object please set your value.

Only less polite because this is programming not etiquette school.

Comment: I wonder when we'll see an etiquette based esoteric programming language. "Look I really hate to be a bother again, but would you mind executing the *Main* method with a parameter of *x*?"
**--Runtime exception: You didn't say please.**

Comment: @Rotem: Reality has been there since 1972: See [INTERCAL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INTERCAL#Details) where you have to insert a certain number of `PLEASE` keywords into the code.

Comment: @A.H. I had a feeling I wasn't the first to have thought of it :)